# Loop variables on arduino

Tags: c, loops, variables, arduino

I want do to a loop with some variables on my arduino , I have 24 variables ( ConfigSonde[0][3] to ConfigSonde[24][3] ) to change, i need do to a loop:

EX :

```
ConfigSonde_0[] = {'xxx', 3, 'A', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; 

ConfigSonde_1[] = {'xxx', 1, 'A', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

for (i = 0; i < 25; i = i + 1) { ConfigSonde_[i][3]=0;}
```

Is it possible ?

Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are mixing `int`s and `'xxx'`? (if it's supposed to be a string it must be `"xxx"`), and this is not legal in C.
2. `ConfigSonde_[i][3]` where `i = 0` doesn't give you a reference to the variable `ConfigSonde_0[3]`

Maybe you are looking for:

```
int ConfigSonde_0[] = {'x', 3, 'A', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; 
int ConfigSonde_1[] = {'x', 1, 'A', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int *ConfigSonde [] = {ConfigSonde_0, ConfigSonde_1};

for (i = 0; i < 2; i = i + 1) {ConfigSonde[i][3] = 0;}
```

or

```
int ConfigSonde[][10] = {
    {'x', 3, 'A', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {'x', 1, 'A', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
};

for (i = 0; i < 2; i = i + 1) {ConfigSonde[i][3] = 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Rewrite:** Do do what you need, you're going to have to either add additional variables that point at the things you want to change in the loop, or change your 25 distinct arrays to be a single 2-dimensional array.

You cannot dynamically "compute" names of variables to access their values in C (or C++), since these languages are compiled the names of variables are no longer relevant when the program runs.

Comment: thank but, I have 24 variables ( ConfigSonde[0][3] toConfigSonde[24][3] ) to change, i need do to a loop

Comment: @sebastien So perhaps you should make your question reflect your actual problem, then? :)